# Trouble with callbacks, error catching and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been working on an application which allows me to add companies to a database. Originally my code was pure spaghetti, so I wanted to modularize it properly. For this purpose, I added routes, a controller and a dao.

This is how my code looks right now

***Routes***

```
  app.post('/loadcompanies', (req, res)=> {
    companiesController.loadcompany(req.body, (results)=>{
      console.log(results);
      res.send(200, "working!");
    })   
  })
```

Controller

```
module.exports.loadCompany = (body, callback)=>{
    companiesDao.loadCompany(body, callback);
}
```

Dao

```
module.exports.loadCompany = (company, callback)=>{
MongoClient.connect(conexionString, (err, database) => { 
    if (err) console.log(err);
    db = database;
    console.log(company);
    db.collection('companies').insert(company, (err, result)=>{
        callback({message:"Succesfully loaded company", company:result});    
    });
  })   
}
```

My current concern is that working with errors when modularizing like this is confusing. I tried adding a try-catch method around the db insert and throwing and error if there is one, but that doesn't seem to work. Other things I've tried is returning the error in the callback, like this:

```
if (err) callback (err, null);
```

but I end up getting a "Can't set headers after they are sent." error.

How would you handle errors in this situation? For example, in the case that someone tries to add a duplicate entry in an unique element.

Comment: callbacks and error checking have always been tricky, I would suggest you look into using promises, and then look into async / await to make things even better.

Comment: As an addendum, in my original spaghetti application i'd just have it res send a 503 when the mongodb had an error and that was that

Comment: I'll look into promises and async await for sure, since callbacks can be really confusing haha, but the examples for these cases seem to be mostly with callbacks.
Thanks!

Comment: Just looked at MongoClient, if you don't supply a callback, they return a Promise..  And if your using the recent version of Node.js, you can use async / await.. :)   I'll post an example of async/await..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply do the error checking inside the callback for the insert function:

```
db.collection('companies').insert(company, (err, result)=>{
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
        return;
    }
    callback(null, {message:"Succesfully loaded company", company:result});    
});
```

If you get an error like you say, that's probably because the database is actually returning an error. You could also make your errors more specific, like:

```
module.exports.loadCompany = (company, callback)=>{
MongoClient.connect(conexionString, (err, database) => { 
    if (err) {
        callback(new Error('Connection error: ' + err.Error());
        return;
    }
    db = database;
    console.log(company);
    db.collection('companies').insert(company, (err, result)=>{
        if (err) {
            callback(new Error('Insertion error: ' + err.Error());
            return;
        }
        callback(null, {message:"Succesfully loaded company", company:result});    
    });
})
```

Comment: Just a note, you either do  `if (err) {} else {},`  or do `if (err) return callback()` because what will happen in this code is will do the error callback, and then do the successful callback as well..

Comment: No problem, easy to do. Another thing I've spotted, for your success callbacks don't forget to put `callback(null, result)`.. It's these things that make me instantly convert into promises when I see these, and then use async / await.  Saying that even using async / await I can sometimes forget the await..

Comment: Fixed again. Yeah, there's a lot of little gotchas with callbacks. The worst is how hard they are to debug if you mess up. I once spent hours tracking down a bug which eventually boiled down to that same problem... Missing the null in the success callback.

Comment: This actually worked! Turns out having a callback for an error without putting the other callback in an else can lead to errors, which was my issue! 

I had tried doing an if-else in that case but I forgot to put the res.send in the success case inside an else too, and that's why I was getting the "Can't set headers after they are sent." error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your loadCompany done in async / await format.

Notise there is no need for error checking, errors will propagate as expected up the promise chain.

Note I've also changed loadCompany to be an async function too, so to call it you can simply do `var ret = await loadCompany(conpanyInfo)`

```js
module.exports.loadCompany = async (company)=>{
  let db = await MongoClient.connect(conexionString);
  console.log(company);
  let result = await db.collection('companies').insert(company);
  return {message:"Succesfully loaded company", company:result};    
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) i've read on the advantages of promises and i'll absolutely begin using them in my code.

the call to this method would need to be through a promise with await too, right? from the controller and the routes